# Using OpenCV and ffmpeg to write MP4 files

Tags: c++, opencv, video, ffmpeg

I want to write MP4 video files using openCV. However, judging by this [issue](http://code.opencv.org/issues/1934), it looks like that is not possible. Currently, I am writing the file as an avi and then a system call to ffmpeg for conversion to MP4. This is obviously slow. 
Is there some way I can speed this up?

One idea I had was to inject the frame I generate using openCV into ffmpeg directly. But to do that I will have to write them to file from openCV and read that file from ffmpeg, which is time consuming. Is there some way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

It's called a pipe:

```
command1 | command2
```

connects `command1`'s output to `command2`'s input. Yes, `ffmpeg` does support reading data from stdin. I don't know if OpenCV does; you'll have to read the documentation. If it doesn't, you can try using `/dev/stdout` as the filename to write to, or using a named pipe.